# SSIS Data transformation Specific rows

Tags: ssis

Is there any way in SSIS by which I can transform only 1000 rows on every run.For E.g.from 0 to 1000 for first time run.Second time 1001 to 2000 and likewise till end of data in source.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM MySource

Comment: It will select same data everytime. I want next 1000 rows on every run of ssis package. 0-1000 on first run. 1001-2000 on second.2001-3000 on third and so on...

Comment: then you add `WHERE MyKey BETWEEN ? and ? ORDER BY MyKey` and assign parameters to match

Comment: I do not want to hardcode these values everytime.It has to take it automatically.Is it possible in SSIS?

Comment: which is why I specified you would assign parameters. Your problem is then reduced to determining your boundaries: the last modified, last transmitted, as of, etc key. Package then becomes 1) Determine where we left off 2) Move data. Each invocation of package will proceed until all the data has been moved. This has been covered, many times over. Have you done any research at all on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this before, but this should get you half way there...

Create a variable named something like iRows (or whatever floats your boat). 
In your source, add a column named something like IsSelected (bit, default 0)

Create a For Loop. 
Inside the For Loop create your data flow Task
  Source:  SELECT TOP 1000 whatever FROM your_table WHERE IsSelected = 0
  Somewhere in your data flow task create an OLEDB command that sets IsSelected = 1
  Somewhere in your data flow task create a RowCount variable so it counts rows, and set it to iRows.  Should be 1000 with each loop until the last one, and eventually 0. 
Edit the For..Loop EvalExpression to be iRows = 0.

Good luck.
Jim